# How to install Meteor.js on windows 10?

Tags: meteor, chocolatey

I am trying to install meteor.js on my windows 10 machine.

I have gone through https://www.meteor.com/install for installation. But the site asking me to install chocolatey software https://chocolatey.org/install.

chocolatey is not getting installed since

```
 getExecutionPolicy was returning - restricted.
```

And on execution of

```
 Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
```

is returning:
[image: error screen]

Comment: Please, reread the installation procedure; they're asking for your email to subscribe you the the newsletter.

Comment: @HarryAdel I was getting error while installing chocolatey. The issue is fixed when I ran the powershell as administrator.

Comment: Ah, I see. My bad for not reading your question thoroughly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is resolved when I tried opening powershell with administrator.

right click on

```
  powershell -> right click -> run as adminstrator
```

and follow the same procedure as above like setExecutionPolicy.

It will give you now

[image: success image]

After installation of chocolatey run command as:

```
 choco install meteor
```